# Filter dataframe based on the presence of multiple columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am curious what is the best practice to do the following:
Let's say I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  3  5  5
2  1  2  3  4
3  3  5  6  7
4  9  7  6  5

df2:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  9  7  6
```

I want to filter down df1 on columns A, B, C to only show records which are present in df2's A,B,C columns.
The result I want to see:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  9  7  6  5
```

As you can see I only need records from df1 where the combination of the first 3 columns are either 1,2,3 or 9,7,6.

What I tried is a bit overkill in my opinion:

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how="left", on=["A", "B", "C"], indicator=True)
mask = merged_df["_merge"] == "both"
result = merged_df[mask].drop(["_merge"], axis=1)
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: why do you say it is "overkill"?

Comment: because there is an additional column created which i need to drop.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?..Deos it helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge on `inner`

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 1, 1,3,9],
        "B": [2,3,2,5,7],
        "C": [3,5,3,6,6],
         "D": [4,5,4,7,5]
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 9],
        "B": [2,7],
        "C": [3,6],
        
    }
)

#print(df1)

df =pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B', 'C'], how='inner')

print(df)
```

output #

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  9  7  6  5
```